# intialze 2 dimensional array in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to initialize memory using 2 dimensional array via Xinlix software. Code is syntactically correct, but its testbench is giving unexpected output.

For example:

`address 0:instruction=1081601; but required output=00108101`

and

`address 1:instruction=1048834;   required output=00100102`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
module Imem ( address, instruction);
  input [31:0]  address;
  output     reg [31:0] instruction;

  reg [31:0]sra [0:256];integer i;

  //    I-mem is read in every cycle.
  //    A read signal could be added if necessary.
  always @(address)
  begin
    sra[32'h00000000]=32'h00108101;
    sra[32'h00000001]=32'h00100102;
    sra[32'h00000002]=32'h34100020;
    sra[32'h00000003]=32'h38100020;
    sra[32'h00000004]=32'h00108105;
    sra[32'h00000005]=32'h00108106;
    sra[32'h00000006]=32'h00108147;
    sra[32'h00000007]=32'h00100148;
    sra[32'h00000008]=32'h0010810F;
    sra[32'h00000009]=32'h00108109;
    sra[32'h0000000A]=32'h0010014A;
    sra[32'h0000000B]=32'h0010810B;
    sra[32'h0000000C]=32'h8C105555;
    sra[32'h0000000D]=32'hAC10AAAA;
    sra[32'h0000000E]=32'h31555555;
    sra[32'h0000000F]=32'h28A00000;
    sra[32'h00000010]=32'h00000000;
    sra[32'h00000011]=32'h00000000;

    for(i=32'd18;i<=32'd256;i=i+1)
        sra[i]=32'h00000000;

    instruction=sra[address];
  end

endmodule
```

My testbench is:

```
module instr_v_v;

    // Inputs
    reg [31:0] address;

    // Outputs
    wire [31:0] instruction;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    Imem uut ( 
        .address(address), 
        .instruction(instruction)
    );

    initial 
    begin
        address=32'd0;
        $display($time,"address=%h,instruction=%h",address,instruction);
        // Initialize Inputs


        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish

        #10 address=32'd1;
        #10 address=32'd2;
        #10 address=32'd3;
        #10 address=32'd4;

        // Add stimulus here
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Please share your testbench. I'm guessing there is a wrong radix somewhere as 1081601 decimal is 108101 hexadecimal. Or it code be a scheduling issue.

Comment: The provided testbench doesn't have the checker that generated the errors. Currently this question, lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I'm working on Xinlinx ISE 8.2 version.Mr. Greg u have asked for testbench and i have shared it,but now u r saying that question lacks sufficient information.what else information do u want regarding code?in fact,i'm getting tensed when everthing is ok with my code and code is still giving unexpected output.

Comment: The code for that generated two error messages is missing. To solve the problem, we need to have enough information to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its working correctly, I changed the tb to below which after you drive each address you wait 1 time unit to display the value.

Waveform: http://img42.com/8ED7S

This should be the output

```
              11address=00000000,instruction=00108101
              22address=00000001,instruction=00100102
              33address=00000002,instruction=34100020
              44address=00000003,instruction=38100020
              55address=00000004,instruction=00108105



initial 
begin
    #10 address=32'd0;
    #1 $display($time,"address=%h,instruction=%h",address,instruction);
    // Initialize Inputs


    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish

    #10 address=32'd1;
      #1 $display($time,"address=%h,instruction=%h",address,instruction);
    #10 address=32'd2;
      #1 $display($time,"address=%h,instruction=%h",address,instruction);
    #10 address=32'd3;
      #1 $display($time,"address=%h,instruction=%h",address,instruction);
    #10 address=32'd4;
      #1 $display($time,"address=%h,instruction=%h",address,instruction);

    // Add stimulus here
end
```